# SearchView: How get height of suggestion list?

Tags: android, searchview

In my fragment I have searchView (not in toolBar)

Here fragment's snippet:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);  
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter(getActivity()));
```

My custom addapter:  `SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter`

And here result:

[image: sarchview_suggestion_list]

As you can see when I click on searView then show suggestion list and softkeyboard is show.

The question is: Is it possible to get suggestion's list height (when click on searchView)?

Comment: It's not duplicate. In first question I need position of first and last items. In this question I need to get height of suggestion list.

Comment: height? what do you need it for?

Comment: I need suggestion list to has fix height. And not change height when user input text. So if I have it's height I (maybe) can set fix height of it.

Comment: i am afraid you cannot do that

Comment: Is it possible to get count of visible items in drop-down?

Comment: yes: `SearchCatalogSuggestionsAdapter` extends `CursorAdapter` so read `android.widget.Adapter` documentation